# Sharepoint2013 Modal Dialog box is not loading

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Hi I have a simple page uploaded to SharePoint pages library and trying to simulate long running operation with no close wait dialog. 
Below is the is script what i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var waitDialog = null;
    function DoWork() {
        toggleProcessingStatus(true);
        UpdateUI();
        toggleProcessingStatus(false);
    }
    function UpdateUI()
    {
        var lblControl = document.getElementById("lbl");
        for (i = 0; i < 20000; i++) 
        {            
            lblControl.innerText = lblControl.innerText + i;
        }
    }
    function toggleProcessingStatus(showStatus) {
        if (showStatus) {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ShowWaitDialog, "sp.js");
        }
        else {
            if (waitDialog != null) {
                //setTimeout(CloseWaitDialog, 5000);
                CloseWaitDialog();
            }
        }
    }
    function ShowWaitDialog() {
        waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Updating...', 'Please wait while update completes...', 150, 330);
    }

    function CloseWaitDialog() {
        if (waitDialog != null) {
            waitDialog.close();
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnShowDialog" title="Do Long Running Work" name="Do Long Running Work" onclick="javascript: DoWork();" value="Do Long Running Work"/>
Label: <label id="lbl" title="Test">Test Wait Screen</label>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mallikarjun

Answer (score 1):

"sp.ui.dialog.js" must be loaded.

I have added below code to curent page that I wanted to open dialogbox.

Answer (score 0):

try ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ShowWaitDialog, "sp.ui.js");

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers mentioned, you need to ensure that the script sp.ui.dialog.js script is loaded. You can do this with code similar to below

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}, "sp.ui.dialog.js");
//ensure script is loaded
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.ui.dialog.js", null, null);
```

The inclusion of both `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` **and** `executeFunc` in this pattern ensures the following:

- executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded - wait until sp.ui.dialog is loaded before executing enclosed code
- executeFunc - ensure sp.ui.dialog is loaded, if it already has not been requested by the page

Answer (score 0):

Try _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('functionName');

In your case

`if (showStatus) {
            _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(ShowWaitDialog);
}`